# How can I add a small matrix into a big one with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to figure out how to take a small matrix (Matrix `B` below) and add the values into a larger matrix (Matrix `A` below) at a certain index. It seems like numpy would be a good option for this scenario but I can't figure out how to do it.

Matrix `A`:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Matrix `B`:

```
[[2, 3, 4]
 [5, 6, 7]
 [8, 9, 3]]
```

Desired end result:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0]
 [0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0]
 [0, 0, 8, 9, 3, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Could you please let us know what you have attempted, even if it just means reading up on the documentation? What sources have you consulted so far?

Comment: You just gotta find the index range of A where you want to put B. Something like: `A[1:4,2:6]=B`

Comment: When you say "add the values" do you mean the mathematical addition operation, or another way of saying "place the values"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to add `B` to `A` with the upper left-hand corner of `B` going to index `(r, c)` in `A`, you can do it using the index and the `shape` attribute of `B`:

```
A[r:r+B.shape[0], c:c+B.shape[1]] += B
```

If you want to just set the elements (overwrite instead of adding), replace `+=` with `=`. In your particular example:

```
>>> A = np.zeros((5, 6), dtype=int)
>>> B = np.r_[np.arange(2, 10), 3].reshape(3, 3)

>>> r, c = 1, 2

>>> A[r:r+B.shape[0], c:c+B.shape[1]] += B
>>> A
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 8, 9, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The indexing operation produces a *view* into `A` since it is simple indexing, meaning that the data is not copied, which makes the operation fairly efficient for large arrays.

Answer (score 5):

You can pad the b array into the same shape with a.
[numpy.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0]])

b = np.array([[2,3,4],
 [5,6,7],
 [8,9,3]])


b = np.pad(b, ((1,1) , (2,1)), mode = 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))

print(a+b)
```

After padding b will be

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 3 4 0]
 [0 0 5 6 7 0]
 [0 0 8 9 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

a+b will be

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 3 4 0]
 [0 0 5 6 7 0]
 [0 0 8 9 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The `((1,1) , (2,1))` means you add 1 row on top, one row on bottom, 2 columns on left, 1 columns on right. All added row and columns are zeros because of `mode = 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0)`.

So you can input the index you want to add the matrix

Comment: Not as efficient as the reverse approach of creating a view into A, but clever nevertheless. +1

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I think your answer is more efficient, because my answer use more memory. Thanks! +1 for you too.